Should the quantum and classical parts of the Maxwell-Liouville equation be solved self-consistently?
Should the Maxwell-Liouville equation be solved self-consistently or is that unnecessary?
In semi-classical theory for nonlinear optics it is common to treat the electromagnetic field $E(r,t)$ classically, while the induced polarization $P(r,t)$ is derived using quantum mechanics. The equations to solve are
$$
\nabla \times \nabla \times E(r,t) + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E(r,t) = -\frac{4\pi}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 P(r,t)}{\partial t^2} \tag{1}
$$
$$
P(r,t) = \textrm{Tr}[\hat P(r)\hat \rho(t)], \tag{2}
$$
where $\hat P$ is the dipole moment operator times the number density of dipoles in the sample. $\hat \rho$ is the density operator of the system,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\hat \rho = -i/\hbar [\hat H(t), \hat \rho] \tag{3} 
$$
$$
\hat H= \hat T + \hat V  -\hat \mu\cdot  E \tag{4}
$$
The time evolution of $\hat \rho$ does itself depend on the classical field $E$ by means of the Hamilton operator that contains the light-matter interaction with the field, but typically, when the equation is solved, one assumes a incoming pulse or plane wave that is independent of $P$, and clearly not the same as the total field in equation (1). But the classical field $E$ should be the same in (1) and (4), or shouldn't it?
It seems like one would need to do the whole process iteratively, since we know neither $E(r,t)$ that should enter our Hamiltonian, nor $P(r,t)$ that is required to find $E$. I don't think I have ever heard any mention of such an iterative procedure, which makes me wonder if I misunderstand something.
Why is it justified to use a different field $E$ in (1) and (4) as is often done in semiclassical nonlinear optics literature (for example Principles of Nonlinear Optical Spectroscopy by Shaul Mukamel), where the field in (4) is typically assumed to be some set of pre-defined pulses?
EDIT
I have difficulties to nail down my problem, so I'll describe my confusion. A typical setup in nonlinear spectroscopy starts with an incoming field that is focused on a probe, for example two different monochromatic waves from two lasers. The incoming field is then simply the sum
$$
\vec E_{\textrm{inc}}(\vec r,t) = \vec E_1 \exp(-i\omega_1t + i\vec k_1 \cdot \vec r) + \vec E_2 \exp(-i\omega_2t + i\vec k_2 \cdot \vec r) + c.c.
$$
I can in principle plug this field into equation (4) and then solve for the polarization given by (2). The question is then how does this field enter (1) and is it supposed to be equal to the field on the left-hand side? The way in which the equations are written it seems like they have to be the same.
But that would mean one must solve all equation consistently, which seems next to impossible,  and a sum of two monochomatic waves is certainly not sufficient to describe all possible solutions or nonlinear effects for this example.
Or is $E$ on the left-hand side just some contribution to some sort of total field $E_{\textrm{total}}=E + E_{\textrm{inc}}$, where $E$ satisfies (1) based on a polarization calculated with $E_{\textrm{inc}}$, with $E$ and $E_\textrm{inc}$ not functionally related?
I am not looking for calculations in details, rather the general logic which I seem to misunderstand.

To get better answers, you should quote more extensively from the books you're asking about. Without having Mukamel's book, the best guess I can make is that they're doing some kind of perturbation analysis. If you suppose the polarization produced in response to a strong pulse $E_0$ is small, then it produces a small electric field $E_1$ of its own. Then (4) only needs to include $E_0$, as the effect of $E_1$ would be doubly small, but (1) relates $P$ to the small field $E_1$ it creates.

Firstly, let me point out that treating EM field classically while taking account for quantum effects in material equations is a very common approach. One could just think of Fermi Golden rule or Kubo formula (note that both describe linear response.) This mostly has to do with the fact that in many experiments the EM field is very big, compared to the quantum fluctuations, i.g., it contains many photons, and these fluctuations can be neglected. One could think of a typical spectroscopy experiment, where the discreteness of the atomic levels and Zeeman splitting are by far larger than the Lamb shift (which is due to the field quantum fluctuations.) This also holds for many applications in laser physics or many-body physics (see, e.g., Yariv's Quantum electronics, Baslev and Stahl's Electrodynamics of semiconductor band edge or even books like Mahan's Many-particle physics.)
Thus, the problem in question is not really about combining quantum and classical, but about treating non-linear phenomena. Here the fact that phenomenon is non-linear implies that we should look for a self-consistent solution - by linearizing one would throw the baby with the water... although we can (and do) linearize near the equilibrium points, or when studying stability of stable solutions.
There is a wide range of mathematical techniques, applicable to different situations, including those that allow taking account an external perturbation. A classical example is that of a forced van-der-Pol oscillator, where one deals with non-linear mixing of response to the external force, and own non-linear oscillations.
What might be confusing in problems dealing with EM fields is that both the external field and the response are the same electromagnetic field. There are different situations that come to mind how this can be deal with (which depends on the context):

the external field could be treated as a component of the total field that remains unchanged - e.g., because it is generated by a very strong generator. In this case we would decompose the total field as $E=E_{ext}+E_{nonlinear}$, and solve self-consistently only for $E_{nonlinear}$
the external field may be treated as a small perturbation - this is essentially an extension of the previous approach, but the equations are expanded to the first order in $E_{ext}$
one may not solve self-consistently, but perturbatively - considering, e.g., the second and third order responses to the perturbation (rather than only the first-order response, as in linear theory.)

I do not claim that this list is exhaustive - there are perhaps other approaches, but that would require asking a more specific question.

Yes, my problem is not  classical vs quantum treatment of the field. I guess I didn't state that explicitly enough in the question, but the field in all equations is classical and equations 2-4 imply a semi-classical treatment. Your last three points are helpful.

@HansWurst I am still not sure that I understand your question correctly: the field is always a superposition of the external field and the field generated in the system (since the Maxwell equations in vacuum are linear), non-linearity arises when the fields are mixed by the material, which generates a new field... but part of the net field still comes from the external sources, which are not accounted in the material equations, and which in your case are represented by their result - $E_{inc}$. These sources are assumed to be unaffected by the non-linear response of the system..

@HansWurst note also that your $E_{inc}$ satisfies the Maxwell equation without the rhs, so there is no problem in including it or not as a component of the total field in the first equation. This external field however must be included in Eq. (4).

I am still reading literature, but it seems your second comment is what many books do without stating it clearly. I.e. treating the first order polarization contribution different to higher orders. Many texts include linear dispersion and absorption in the first order solution, leading to the Lambert-Beer law(with some approximations.) But this solution is clearly not intended to be added to the incoming field, but is the total field at the end. This seems not be true when higher orders are calculated, which are simply added to the first order solution to obtain the total field.

Which leads back to my question. The whole approach is approximate and in principle not self-consistent. I.e. it does only approximately solve the Maxwell-Liouville equation, like time-dependent perturbation theory only approximately solves the Schrödinger equation for example.

@HansWurst Solution for the induced field could be self-consistent (in principle) - the only inconsistency comes from connecting the system to the outside world... but this is what makes the problem meaningful, if you are looking for a response (e.g., to a bi-harmonic signal) you need to have an input and output. The problem here might be more philosophical than physical. Studying self-consistently properties of a system isolated from the outside is a different class of problems.
